# How to create Journal entry in QuickBooks Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to use C# to create a Journal entry in [Quickbooks Online V3 API](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#JournalEntry).

Things I have done:

- Check JSON Values and format
- Checked Header and accept.

Header info:

```
Accept : application/json
Authorization : OAuth oauth_token="************",oauth_nonce="cfc36792-8f9a-4202-9fec-be0a610eed8e",oauth_consumer_key="************",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1435189421",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="***"
Content-Length : 642
Content-Type : application/json
Host : qb.sbfinance.intuit.com

//till here everything is fine not sure about last two lines..
//not sure should i add this to my header or not..

X-NewRelic-ID : UQMAU15RGwcAUllSDwc=
X-NewRelic-Transaction : PxQAVVRUCgMIUiRXdHMBICETGlUDChAHHEAPVgoPBgILU3xUciMFJCEUG0MDUwFVAV1WVBVs
```

My code:

```
   public static void Main()
        {

         //   JournalEndPoint lnew = new JournalEndPoint();
           // string Json=lnew.CreateJournal();

            string consumerKey = "***";
            string consec = "***";
            string appkeysec1 = "***";
            string appkey1 = "***";

            string returnvalue = ExecuteV3Query(consumerKey, consec, appkey1, appkeysec1, "1397754725", "select * from employee where active=TRUE");

        }
        public static string ExecuteV3Query(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret, string CompanyId, string query)
        {
            string encodedQuery = RestSharp.Contrib.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);
            string uri = string.Format("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{0}/journalentry", CompanyId, encodedQuery);
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            string JSonvalue = CreateUserJson();
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, httpWebRequest, null));
            //HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            /*
             * using (Stream data = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                //return XML response
                return new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
            }
            */


            var result = "";
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
            try
            {
                httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run." +
                                    "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
                if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
                    using (Stream data = e.Response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                    {
                        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                        result = text;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

`GetDevDefineHeader()` will create header and return type is string.

Comment: The last two headers lines are inserted into your header automatically by a newrelic plugin. You do not have to add them yourself.

Comment: @BrokenBinary Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?? I am trying this thing from past 3 hrs but getting same error.. please help me

Answer (score 0):

In your url, I do not see the use of encoded query and why are you passing it?

Please check the docs for correct endpoints for CRUD and query operations-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/JournalEntry

See this example for GET using dev defined-

https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/0913b4c224de758fde0a

Similarly there is a post example here, you can write similarly for JE-

```
//string res = CreateV3Customer(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, realmId);

public string CreateV3Customer(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret, string realmId)
    {

        StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();



        var requestBody = "{\"FamilyName\":\"Jack\"}";

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/"+realmId+"/customer") as HttpWebRequest;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken,accessTokenSecret,httpWebRequest, requestBody));
        request.Append(requestBody);
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] content = encoding.GetBytes(request.ToString());
        using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream data = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {


          string customerr = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();

          return customerr;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am just passing it, not using it... That was for employee, I was trying before journal entry... i have created separate class and for question purpose i have written everthing in single class so may be I forgot to remove it.. but the JSON i m created i correct, may be there is issue with header, checked endpoints... I dont know what i am doing wrong ... Can you help me with this ??

Comment: See the code above and compare yours with it. I see only encoding is diff. That you have not done.

Comment: Headers req- POST https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/717093040/query HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Host: quickbooks.api.intuit.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="lvprdBmi45KMPO2FnvYtq6KLFTMM7KG0P0PJO3Sm7F3n7pgq",oauth_nonce="e5d6e732-f903-4456-9c5f-58103843c3c6",oauth_consumer_key="qyprd7I5WvVgJZUvWDFnPoiBh1ejZn",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1394005668",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="J8qgGZRa4loR6HEtdpAudP1nVpw%3D"

Comment: Unless you paste the full url and error response, we can't debug what is the issue. Anways comparing the code itself should provide you the pointers.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the .net sdk 2.2.0? Oauth and service calls wrapper is provided there. You need not create separate classes for it. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0     Check the sample app for .net too-https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-DotNet

Comment: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<IntuitResponse time=\"2015-06-25T01:38:41.808-07:00\" xmlns=\"http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3\">\n    <Fault type=\"AUTHENTICATION\">\n        <Error code=\"3200\">\n            <Message>message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401</Message>\n        </Error>\n    </Fault>\n</IntuitResponse>\n"

Comment: do u have any link for c# lib, I want to do some customization... if possible can you provide me that... thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81505/discussion-between-user3788832-and-nimisha-shrivastava).

Comment: The above sdk/c# lib link is for QBO v3 services. It works for both web apps as well as desktop apps with an embedded browser for oauth. Boht links have been shared above